Differing copies of the 1917 Scofield Reference Bible
In the following 2 copies of the Scofield Reference Bible, footnote number 1 to Romans 3:21 for the word "righteousness" on page 1194 ends with "Phil. 3.9.":
https://archive.org/details/scofieldreferenc00unse/page/1194

https://archive.org/details/holybible0000unse_f2h3/page/1194
Both copies are "Scofield Facsimile Series No. 2" as printed in the lower right corner of the title page (link and link).
On the other hand, in the following copy (as well as in a printed copy that I have from Church Bible Publishers), "See Rom. 3.26." has been added:
https://archive.org/details/scofieldreferenc0000revc/page/1194

This one is "Scofield Facsimile Series No. 1" (link) and has one more name listed under "Consulting Editors", namely Rev. William L. Pettingill, D.D. My printed copy from Church Bible Publishers does not have this title page at all.
The additional reference "See Rom. 3.26." is also in a copy "Digitized by Google" with "Original from University of Michigan", which I cannot find online anymore, but I have a local copy downloaded some time ago (SHA256SUM d0f48765b9eb8a9e399afe0e46e7282cf8add44efe49d08d912b208b1d69f0a0) and which is "Scofield Facsimile Series No. 2" and with only 7 consulting editors, like the first 2 copies. So the difference in the footnote to Romans 3:21 does not correspond in a systematic manner to the differences on the title page!
On the surface, all of those copies are the 1917 edition, judging by the preface dated Jan. 1, 1917.
Any ideas why this difference? Are there other known places where the two versions differ? Is there a reason to consider one of them more reliable?

Welcome to the site, Lasse. How remarkable that you noted that ever so slight difference in the two copies! I hope someone can answer why that additional scripture reference occurred, perhaps by checking out the Bunyan source for the last 4 lines. Even more remarkable is how the first 4 lines of the footnote appear to contradict what Bunyan said! I feel a question coming on!

This is on page 1194, now also added to the text of the question. I always try to compare different sources for important documents. In this case, amazingly, I found the difference almost instantly, it took not even a minute.

And there was I, hastily removing my request for that page number, seeing it after I posted my initial comment! Your speed is commendable!


Is there a reason to consider one of them more reliable?

You could apply a hermeneutical method:

If "See Rom. 3.26." was an addition to the original, it should be relevant and improve the other content.
If "See Rom. 3.26." was a deletion from the original, it should be irrelevant or inappropriate for the other content.


Or, simply look at the copyright information at the beginning of the books:


But that doesn't really help; I would have expected the single-dated version to be copyright 1909, not 1917.
Both editions have a "Preface to the present edition", dated 1917.
Ah, at the bottom of the title page are:

and

Notice the "Scofield Facsimile Series No. 1" and "… No. 2".
And it looks like the confusing single "1917" date was actually a mistake that was also corrected in "No. 2".
Which would mean that the "See Rom. 3.26." was actually removed in the newer printing.

Copy 1 (scofieldreferenc00unse) has the most consistent copyright notice. Copy 2 (holybible0000unse_f2h3) is also "Scofield Facsimile Series No. 2" but only has the single "1917" copyright notice. The copy from Google that I mentioned is "Scofield Facsimile Series No. 2" but has the additional "See Rom. 3.26.", I put few pages here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EiH-YuEThrcrpj8gHn5f4lDZ0babqta3
